# Mysql - empty value in date field

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add a joindate field in company table:

```
alter table company add joindate date;
```

And I want to set empty value in the joindate field:

```
$joindate = '';
```

Update query:

```
$query = "UPDATE company 
          SET joindate = '" .$joindate. "' 
          WHERE ID = '" .$ID. "'";
```

When I update the record, it show the following warnings:

```
Data truncated for column 'joindate' ...
```

Why? How should I set the empty value in the joindate field?

Comment: What is your query for PHP?

Comment: Make sure your column's length is correct. Most likely an issue with the column misalignment.

Answer (score 1):

Column type is `date`, not `varchar` (or some string type). So you must write correct date by format or `NULL`. Empty string `''` is not correct value so your value is truncated and inserted `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow the value to be null in the columns rules. Unless for some reason, you need an 'empty value'.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to enter a string in a date column. That is not allowed and the data is truncated/removed; lowest date of 0000-00-00 is entered instead.

My recommendation is to just keep the value as NULL, which is what joindate will have across all rows when you add joindate column. There is nothing wrong with that column containing no value (represented by NULL).

If you were to do `alter table tablename add field1 int` and then `update tablename set field = '' where id = 1`, you will receive similar warning `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'field1' at row 1` and that column will receive a value of 0.